What do when getting this error when using open function: FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
Edit: to include file name as suggested by OldBoy.
i've had very, very basic experience and knowledge in python. i appreciate all your help in advance. but as part of a process improvement intiative at my work, i am hoping to write a script that will read through txt files (ideally PDF files but will start with txt files for now as an easier basis) in any folder of choice decided upon by the user and return a list of files that contain a certain key #word (and ideally multiple key words) also inputted by the user.
But i am getting an error with the open function and i think it's because it cannot find the path. but have i not defined the path earlier in my code? any help or insight would be greatly appreciated.
thanks so much!
import os
path=input('Enter file path where the files are found: ') 
#i want user to be able to enter exact path where their files are found
files = os.listdir(path)


#this code is to ONLY get txt files (for now; as my modules PDFquery, PDFminer, PyPDF2 are not working)
split_file_ext = []
for file in files:
        split_file_ext.append(file.split('.'))
#print(split_file_ext)

txt_file_only = []
for x in range(len(split_file_ext)):
        if 'txt' in split_file_ext[x]:
                txt_file_only.append('.'.join(split_file_ext[x]))
        else:
            pass

print(txt_file_only)

user_word = input("Enter key word you are looking for: ")
for file_name in txt_file_only:
#here is where the error occurs
    with open(file_name, 'r') as doc:
         document = doc.readlines()

    for x in range(len(document)):
        if user_word in document[x]:
                print ("Yes it is found in [name]")
        else:
            pass 

Code works until it gets to the read part and the error i get is:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File redacted address due to personal info, line 23, in <module>
with open(file_name, 'r') as doc:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 2000007222 RN 21.JUL.2016.txt
But code is able to ask input for user and print the list of txt files.
There are 4 other txt files in the folder with the same format of 10digit-code followed by RN followed by a date.
Thanks in advance again!

Please show  the actual name of the file that your code is trying to open. Without that information it is not possible to suggest what may be wrong.
